# LaTeX: diplay two headers over a two-column page

Tags: fancyhdr, two-column

I need to make a header using a package like fancyhdr that spans only one column of my two-column page.
the code is here

Comment: Where is 'here'?

Answer (score 2):

Something like this:

```
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\lhead{\parbox{\columnwidth}{\thepage \hfill foo}}
\rhead{\parbox{\columnwidth}{foo\hfill\thepage}}
```

[image]